# How to calculate second order derivative on image

Tags: image, matlab, derivative

I want to calculate second and third order derivative on image. I believe the best way is to derive a gaussian filter and then convolve with image.

For example for second order derive gaussian twice and convolve with image or for third order as well.

But another way that I want to ask you is, can we calculate second order with convolving two first derivative gaussian sequentially with image?
for ex. for ixx
we compute:

```
[ix,iy]=imgradientxy(i);

[ixx,ixy]=imgradientxy(ix);
```

Is this true for calculating second order derivative?

Comment: Yes, for the same reason that you can convolve with derivative of gaussian , but get a gaussian of derivative instead https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Differentiation

Comment: i need use imgradientxyz that is new function in matlab 2016 to calculate gradient on x , y, z direction , so as you said  can i calculate izz like this : [ix,iy,iz]=imgradientxyz(i) and [izx,izy,izz]=imgradient(iz); ????

Comment: Make sure that you understand what higher order derivation means in more than one dimension. In 2D, the gradient has 2components that are partial derivatives in x and y direction. The second order derivation corresponds to the Hessian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian: you will have 4 elements:dxdy, dxdx, dydx and dydy. If you work with 3D images gradien has 3 components, hessian - 9. So when you say you need a second derivative it could mean a particular second derivativ (like dxdy) or the whole Hessian, which is 9 (nine) second derivatives, some of which happen to be equal to each other.

Comment: In your case by using imgradien(iz) you will get three elemnts of hesiian. If you need all of them, do the same for ix and iy as well.

Comment: yes i know when we  work on 3d image we will have 9 components , only i need izz that means second order derivative on z directions,so can i use [ix,iy,iz]=imgradientxyz(i) and [izx,izy,**izz**]=imgradient(iz); ?? that izz in second imgradient will be concluded?

Comment: Yes. [filler words to reach minimum comment legth]